# Summation by group based on unique values for nested data in r

Tags: r, group-by, data.table

For the following dataset:

```
a <- data.table(group_v = rep(c("A","B"),each=4),
                type_v1=c(1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5),
                type_v2=c("1","2a","2b","3","4a","4b","4c","5"),
                number_v=c(12,26,26,35,24,24,24,7))
   group_v type_v1 type_v2 number_v
1:       A      1       1       12
2:       A      2      2a       26
3:       A      2      2b       26
4:       A      3       3       35
5:       B      4      4a       24
6:       B      4      4b       24
7:       B      4      4c       24
8:       B      5       5        7
```

Is there a straighforward `data.table` solution that would give the sum of `number_v` by grouping on `type_v1` **without** considering `type_v2`.

The problem with this:

```
a[,sum_num:=sum(number_v),
  .(group_v,type_v2)]
> a
   group_v type_v1 type_v2 number_v sum_num
1:       A      1       1       12      99
2:       A      2      2a       26      99
3:       A      2      2b       26      99
4:       A      3       3       35      99
5:       B      4      4a       24      79
6:       B      4      4b       24      79
7:       B      4      4c       24      79
8:       B      5       5        7      79
```

is that it counts some rows multiple times. The correct output should be:

```
   group_v type_v1 type_v2 number_v sum_num
1:       A       1       1       12      73
2:       A       2      2a       26      73
3:       A       2      2b       26      73
4:       A       3       3       35      73
5:       B       4      4a       24      31
6:       B       4      4b       24      31
7:       B       4      4c       24      31
8:       B       5       5        7      31
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be we need to wrap with `unique`

```
a[, sum_num := sum(unique(number_v)), .(group_v)]
```

But, that may fail to sum the same value across different type_v1.  So, instead of that, we may create a logical index with `duplicated` on 'type_v1'

```
a[, sum_num := sum(number_v[!duplicated(type_v1)]), .(group_v)]
```

-output

```
#    group_v type_v1 type_v2 number_v sum_num
#1:       A       1       1       12      73
#2:       A       2      2a       26      73
#3:       A       2      2b       26      73
#4:       A       3       3       35      73
#5:       B       4      4a       24      31
#6:       B       4      4b       24      31
#7:       B       4      4c       24      31
#8:       B       5       5        7      31
```

Comment: Thanks. Is the `duplicated` approach is more robust since there might be identical `number_v`s across different `type_v1`s?